# What is a difference between Package Service Providers and Application Service Providers?

Tags: laravel

In a config/app.php file I found these comments:

```
    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
```

I would like to add some additional providers. Where should I add them?

Answer (score 3):

These comments are just to keep things separate. All the service providers that comes with application, while be placed under comment like:

```
/*
 * Application Service Providers...
 */

App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
```

On the other hand the package you have installed on the application may have their own service provider. You might need to register those provider in your Laravel(though new Laravel version mostly don't need these as the packages are being auto discovered). So, those package service providers will go under Package Service comment, like:

```
/*
* Package Service Providers...
*/

Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,
Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
```

But, these are just comments nothing else. These are here just to keep things separate and easy to find. You don't need to be very strict about them. You can even delete them and organise your own structure if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Package service providers is where you can write third party service provider.
Application service providers contains Laravel's default service provider.

As for additional service provider I store them in `App\Providers` folder, or you can create your own folder structure. It doesn't matter where you store them.

Answer (score 1):

You can add anywhere within the `'providers'` bracket.

```
'providers' => [
    // ...

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * My Custom Service Providers...
     */
    App\CustomProviders\CustomServiceProvider::class,
    App\Library\LibraryServiceProvider::class,

];
```